# Flutter Banner Ad is not working on real device

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, firebase-admob

My Flutter app is not showing **Banner Ads** from **AdMob Ads** on the real device connected through **Android Studio**. However it shows ads on my Android apps and also **IOS simulators.**

Also, the real IOS device and Simulators are showing all other ads like interstitials and videos.

**Error**:
MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad index 3

**Dependency**:
firebase_admob: ^0.9.1+1

Thank you

Comment: are you doing a debug or release build for your device? You should only be seeing a fake static Ad in your device with the debug key

Comment: As I said, I am able to see the video and interstitial ads. only the Banner ad is not working when using real device. (Video & interstitial) works. On emulator all ads work.

Comment: Have you found something about this ?

Comment: No, I did not change anything but after sometime it automatically started working

Comment: I think that, on iOS only, AdMob needs some time to start showing ads. :)

Comment: Any solution @Sam ? I'm facing the same problem! Ads not showing only on iOS real devices. And the app does not appear on the app linking app store at admob console